wsl --update just tells me "A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated."
I'm running Windows 11, 23H2, 22631.4169.
I've got WSL enabled, installed, and running.
When I open an Ubuntu tab in Terminal, I get a shell prompt. I've been able to, for example, fetch code from github, build it, and run it. WSL works.
But, when I run "wsl --update" in a cmd.exe window with administrator privileges, it gives me the following output:
Installing: Windows Subsystem for Linux
A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.

I ran into the same error during installation and the fix was to enable WSL.
But WSL is already enabled. As mentioned above, it's installed and running and I'm already using it.

"But why are you running wsl --update?"
I'm trying to get Cuda to work in WSL. Followed the steps, got no errors, but it still doesn't work. I saw some instructions that included "wsl --update" and while I don't expect it to help, I figure it can't hurt.

wsl --update is typically run from the user account that is running WSL.  Have you tried without Administrator elevation?
